# Using WinRT/UWP imaging API in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm trying to use WinRT/UWP imaging API in Windows Forms application, for example [BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage). But it always throws exception like:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread, HRESULT:0x8001010E(RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)

Online search shows that is may be related to calling APIs from backgroup thread, but it is called on main thread.

Code example:

```
async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //no throws for this API
        var locator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();

        //throws for this imaging API
        var bi = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
    }
    catch (Exception ee){}
}
```

Environment:

Both VS2017 and VS1029 are tested. Create a blank Windows Forms app (.NET framework 4.8 for VS2019 and 4.7.2 for VS2017 are tested). Then add Nuget package "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" (version 10.0.22621.2 and 10.0.17134.100 are tested) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage will only work in a UWP application context. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SimonMourier Indeed I want to do OCR in WinForms. Windows.Media.Ocr is so easy to use and will have cutting edge performance, so didn't want to waste time do deal with open source OCR libs for WinForms. "will only work in a UWP application context" Is it because of Xaml? Imaging API being bounded to UI framework is really bad design.

Comment: @SimonMourier Will "XAML islands" work for this?

Comment: It's indeed difficult to navigate around UWP vs WinRT vs all technologies... XAML islands may work, but if you need only WinRT's Ocr, you don't need a BitmapImage (Windows.UI.Xaml namespace => UWP XAML), but a SoftwareBitmap ("pure" WinRT).

Comment: This article is nice and explains all dependencies issues https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/05/what-is-actually-the-universal-windows-platform-and-what-is-winui-msix-and-project-reunion/